# primefaces datatable rowIndex -1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm having an issue with getting the `rowIndex` of a Primefaces `dataTable`.

First off, Here is my current operating environment:

> Primefaces 4.1 snapshot; JSF 2.1.24; Apache Tomcat 7.0.30; Mojarra
>   2.1.24; Omnifaces 1.5

On the data table, I have enabled row selection, and in the backing bean I want to get the rowIndex of the selected row in the datatable.  Whenever I try, however, the `DataTable.getRowIndex()` function always  returns `-1`.

Is there any other way that I can get the rowIndex of that row in the table?

**code:**

```
<h:form id="form1">
<p:dataTable id="tbl1" var="train" value="#{bean.Trains}" resizableColumns="true" 
              scrollHeight="750" scrollable="true" sortMode="multiple" filter="true" 
              filteredValue="#{bean.filteredTrains}" style="border:4px solid grey;" 
              rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowKey="#{train.trainId}" 
              selection="#{bean.selectedTrain}" selectionMode="single"
              rowSelectMode="single" >

      <p:ajax event ="rowDblselect" listener="#{bean.onSelect}" update="tbl1" />
```

**Bean Code:**

```
    public void onSelect(SelectEvent event){

    Integer rowIndex = ((DataTable)event.getSource()).getRowIndex();
    System.out.println(rowIndex);

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    DataTable table = (DataTable)facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent(":form1:tbl1");
    Integer rowIndex2 = table.getRowIndex();
    System.out.println(rowIndex2);

}
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to get that ??

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2034 It clearly mentions that rowIndex is for display purpose only.

Comment: Bummer.  Thank  you, though.  I'll try to find another way.  I originally needed it to be able to expand the dataTable's row on double click instead of the <rowToggle/> link that just takes up space.